# Select area by dragging mouse in gwt

Tags: gwt, select, drag, area, drag-and-drop

I am using gwt with [gwt-dnd](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/)  and I want to do the following:

```
1. Select rectangle area by dragging the mouse
2. Select all the elements that are in this area
3. drag all selected elements.
```

Is there any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MouseDownEvent record the coordinates of the pointer (event.getClientX() and eventGetClientY()).

On MouseUpEvent do the same. If coordinates are different, you have a selected rectangular.

Get the widget which contains all the widgets or elements that are selectable. Loop through its children.

Compare coordinates of each widget with your rectangular (use getAbsoluteTop(), getAbdoluteLeft(), getOffsetHeight(), and getOffsetWidth()). Select widgets that are totally or partially inside the selected area.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to Andrei's answer that if you to provide feedback by displaying the rectangle during selection that what we do is display the rectangle as an instance of com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML with a style that displays the borders. This is updated using onMouseMove using setPixelSize and setWidgetPosition.

Answer (score 0):

The library gwtquery-plugins offers a MultiSelect feature, so I will give it a try.

[gwtquery-plugins](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/)